# How to end solving this problem

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove that function can be uniformly approximated by complex polynomials on disk $|z| \leqslant 1$ if and only if $f$ is continuous for $|z| \leqslant 1$ and holomorphic for $|z| \lt 1$.
To prove $\Rightarrow$ direction I used Weierstrass theorem. But I don’t know how to prove backwards.

Comment: How did you use Weierstrass' theorem? And for the $\Rightarrow$ direction? That direction is just uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous $+$ uniform limit of analytic is analytic. The $\Leftarrow$ direction is rather a particular case of [Mergelyan's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mergelyan%27s_theorem)

Comment: Is there an easier proof? Proof for Mergelyans theorem is complicated

Comment: Work will have to be done, unless you use some known theorem in which the work is being hidden. What tools do you have at hand? Maybe you can use [Fejer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem) for the restriction of the function to the circle. Cesaro sums of the Fourier series are complex polynomials. The uniform convergence on the circle gives you uniform convergence in the disc.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy , I’ve got small hint from my teacher. That I shouldn’t use Taylor series (obvious) , but I should use some others polynomials which I need to construct. (Maybe it is Cesaro sums) . It is the first year of studying complex-analysis, so I have got only initial knowledges about series and approximating some functions with them. Sorry for my bad English